# es.json contém uma estrutura inválida de JSON Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

Tenho o arquivo es.json:

```
{
"You are not allowed to do this": "No se te permite hacer esto",
"Error uploading the image": "Error al subir la imagen",
"Something went wrong, please contact support": "Algo salió mal, póngase en contacto con el soporte",
"File deleted with success": "Archivo borrado con éxito",
"Save": "Salvar",
"Close": "Cerrar",
"Delete": "Borrar",
"Created at": "Creado en",
"Actions": "Acción",
"m/d/Y H:i": "",
"m/d/y": "",
"See more...": "Ver más...",
"Search...": "Buscar...",
"Attachments": "Archivos adjuntos",
"High": "Alta",
"Medium": "Medio",
"Low": "Baja",
"Status": "Estado",
"Priority": "Prioridad",
"Logout": "Cerrar sesión",
"Login": "Iniciar Sesión",

"Client inserted with success": "Cliente creado con éxito",
"Client updated with success": "Cliente actualizado con éxito",
"Client deleted with success": "Cliente eliminado con éxito",
"Client": "Cliente",
"Create Client": "Crear cliente",
"Update Client": "Actualizar cliente",
"Delete Client": "Eliminar cliente",
"Are you sure that you want delete this client?": "¿Estás seguro de que quieres borrar este cliente?",
"Clients": "Clientela",

"Comments": "Comentarios",
"Comment": "Comentario",
"Comment inserted with success": "Comentario creado con éxito",
"Comment updated with success": "Comentario actualizado con éxito",
"Comment deleted with success": "Comentario eliminado con éxito",
"Write a comment...": "Escribir un comentario...",
"Delete Comment": "Eliminar comentario",
"Are you sure that you want delete this comment?": "¿Estás seguro de que quieres borrar este comentario?",

"Messages": "Mensajes",
"Message": "Mensaje",
"Message inserted with success": "Mensaje creado con éxito",
"Message updated with success": "Mensaje actualizado con éxito",
"Message deleted with success": "Mensaje eliminado con éxito",

"News": "Noticias",
"News inserted with success": "Noticia creada con éxito",
"News updated with success": "Noticia actualizada con éxito",
"News deleted with success": "Noticia eliminada con éxito",
"Create News": "Crear Noticia",
"Update News": "Actualizar Noticia",
"Delete News": "Eliminar Noticia",
"Are you sure that you want delete this news?": "¿Estás seguro de que quieres borrar esta noticia?",
"No news was found": "No se encontraron noticias",

"Reports": "Informes",
"Report": "Informe",
"Report inserted with success": "Informe creado con éxito",
"Report updated with success": "Informe actualizado con éxito",
"Report deleted with success": "Informe eliminado con éxito",
"Create Report": "Crear Informe",
"Update Report": "Actualizar Informe",
"Delete Report": "Eliminar Informe",
"Are you sure that you want delete this report?": "¿Estás seguro de que quieres borrar este informe?",

"Tickets": "Tickets",
"Ticket": "Ticket",
"Ticket created": "Ticket creado",
"Your ticket was successfully created.": "Su ticket fue creado con éxito",
"Ticket inserted with success": "Ticket creado con éxito",
"Ticket updated": "Ticket actualizado",
"Your ticket was updated.": "Su ticket fue actualizado",
"Ticket updated with success": "Ticket actualizado con éxito",
"Ticket deleted": "Ticket eliminado",
"Your ticket was deleted.": "Su ticket fue eliminado",
"Ticket deleted with success": "Ticket eliminado con éxito",
"Create Ticket": "Crear Ticket",
"Update Ticket": "Actualizar Ticket",
"Delete Ticket": "Eliminar Ticket",
"Are you sure that you want delete this ticket?": "¿Estás seguro de que quieres borrar este ticket?",
"Show completed tickets": "Mostrar tickets completados",

"Message Board": "Tablero de Mensajes",
"Create Message": "Crear Mensaje",
"Update Message": "Actualizar Mensaje",
"Delete Message": "Eliminar Mensaje",
"Are you sure that you want delete this message?": "¿Estás seguro de que quieres borrar esta mensaje?",

"My Profile": "Mi Perfil",
"Dashboard": "Dashboard",

"Name": "Nombre",
"Enter the name": "Ingrese el nombre",
"E-mail": "E-mail",
"Enter the e-mail": "Ingrese el e-mail",
"Image": "Imagen",
"Password": "Contraseña",
"Enter the password": "Ingrese el contraseña",
"Unit": "Unidad",
"Enter the unit": "Ingrese el unidad",
"Notes": "Notas",
"Say something about the client...": "Escriba algo acerca del cliente...",
"Language": "Idioma",
"English": "Inglés",
"Portuguese": "Portugués",
"Spanish": "Español",
"English Title": "Título en inglés",
"Portuguese Title": "Título en portugués",
"Spanish Title": "Título en español",
"Enter the title": "Ingrese el título",
"English Message": "Mensaje en inglés",
"Portuguese Message": "Mensaje en portugués",
"Spanish Message": "Mensaje en español",
"Enter the message": "Ingrese el mensaje",
"English Description": "Descripción en inglés",
"Portuguese Description": "Descripción en portugués",
"Spanish Description": "Descripción en español",
"Enter the description": "Ingrese el descripción",
"Title": "Título",
"Description": "Descripción",

"Hello": "Hola",
"To access it": "Para acceder haz",
"click here": "clic aquí",

"sProcessing":    "Procesando...",
"sLengthMenu":    "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
"sZeroRecords":   "No se encontraron resultados",
"sEmptyTable":    "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
"sInfo":          "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
"sInfoEmpty":     "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
"sInfoFiltered":  "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
"sInfoPostFix":   ".",
"sSearch":        "Buscar:",
"sUrl":           ".",
"sInfoThousands":  ",",
"sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
"sFirst":    "Primero",
"sLast":    "Último",
"sNext":    "Siguiente",
"sPrevious": "Anterior",
"sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
"sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
```

}

já validei ele no jsonlint e ele esta em perfeito estado. Porém o Laravel continua acusando que a estrutura dele está errada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu coloco o arquivo en.json (que é a tradução em inglês) ele também da erro. sendo que quando ele puxa o arquivo en.json ele funciona perfeitamente.

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Realmente o JSON é válido. Você pode tentar remover os espaços e quebras de linhas desnecessárias. Sites que [formatam JSON](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) podem ajudar.

Comment: Também não funcionou!

Comment: Por favor qual código utiliza isso, a sua pergunta falta dizer onde está usando ou isso é automático? como que é isso inserido no Framework...

Comment: O problema foi resolvido, era a codificação que estava errada, estava como UTF-8 with BOM, mudei para somente UTF-8 e funcionou normalmente, devo remover a pergunta, ou respondê-lá?